# What is the syntax to make a callback function variable mutable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, mutable, composable, mutablestateof

I'm trying to make the following variable, *selectedView*, mutable so that I can set the current Composable View dynamically.

```
var selectedView :@Composable () -> Unit =  { testView() }
```

I'm passing back the Composable function and the following code works, but I can't figure out how to make the variable *selectedView* updateable. This would work if  *selectedView* variable was mutable.

```
@Composable
fun testView1() {
    Text("It works! 111")
}

...
    
val navBarItems = listOf(
    NavBarItem("Invite", Icons.Outlined.Send) { testView1() },
    NavBarItem("Messages", Icons.Outlined.Menu) { testView2() },
    NavBarItem("Groups", Icons.Outlined.AccountCircle) { testView3() }
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CurrentView() {
    
    var selectedView :@Composable () -> Unit =  { testView() }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            CustomNavBar(navBarItems){
                selectedView  = it
            }
        }
    )
    {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(it), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            selectedView?.let { it1 -> it1() }
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Compose mutable state to hold it. Something like

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
...
var selectedView by remember {
    mutableStateOf<@Composable () -> Unit>({ TestView() })
}
```

(Note - convention is that `@Composable` functions are named with `UpperCamelCase`)

I see what you're trying to do here, but the problem is going to be dealing with configuration changes. Keeping track of that lambda inside `CurrentView`, it'll get lost and reinitialized on configuration change, such as a screen rotation.

You'd be better served by keeping track of the current screen as a simple value (String, object, enum, etc) as a screen identifier inside a view model (with a saved state handler) or  at least in a `rememberSaveable`.

You could then define either a `when` on the screen identifier to select which `@Composable` to call, or put your lambdas inside a map keyed by the screen identifier.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, thank you! I will look into your other suggestions, I know SwiftUI very well and I'm just starting out with JetPack Compose so I'm sure I'm going down a few wrong rabbit holes in my approach. Thank you for the advice!